# ACF hide menu is not working

Tags: wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF free version included in my plugin but for some reason the admin hide menu is not working.

Please Checkout the bellow code and correct me if I there is missing something. Thanks.

```html
<?php 

// 1. customize ACF path
add_filter('acf/settings/path', 'testio_acf_settings_path');
 
function testio_acf_settings_path( $path ) {
 
    // update path
    $path = FUNC_PLUGIN_DIR . '/admin/lib/acf/acf.php';
    
    // return
    return $path;
    
}
 

// 2. customize ACF dir
add_filter('acf/settings/dir', 'testio_acf_settings_dir');
 
function testio_acf_settings_dir( $dir ) {
 
    // update path
    $dir = FUNC_PLUGIN_DIR . '/admin/lib/acf/acf.php';
    
    // return
    return $dir;
    
}
 

// 3. Hide ACF field group menu item
add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', '__return_false');



// 4. Include ACF
include_once( FUNC_PLUGIN_DIR . '/admin/lib/acf/acf.php' );
include_once( FUNC_PLUGIN_DIR . 'admin/functions/acf-functions.php' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Hide Menu use following code in your plugin

`define( 'ACF_LITE' , true );`

Answer (score 0):

If you use ACF as a plugin instead of the part of theme, just add the following code on your functions.php instead.

```
add_filter('acf/settings/show_admin', '__return_false');
```